# What's the usage of "endDelimiter:@" in db (in my case liquibase)

Tags: delimiter, liquibase

I just started with liquibase and ran into this line in one of the changelogs:

```
--changeset NAME.SURNAME:1 endDelimiter:@ rollbackEndDelimiter:@
```

What is the usage of `"endDelimiter:@"`. I think it replaces the default end-delimiter (character that defines end of line) which is `";"` but why?

Sorry if my question is not formatted properly this is my very first one :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An end delimiter is used if the changeset contains SQL that e.g. creates a stored procedure (or function) where the code itself contains a `;` to separate the statements *inside* the procedure.

If Liquibase split the code using the `;` an incomplete DDL statement would be sent to the database. Therefor you need to have a different delimiter that marks the end of e.g. the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.